# Lambda Example in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, lambda

I am still learning some of the features of C# 3.0 and want to know if the following can be reduced to a lambda expression.

```
var SomeObject = Combo.EditValue;
var ObjectProperty = SomeObject.Property;
```

To obtain ObjectProperty from the combo.editvalue in a single line?

Also, if you can provide me with any good references to Lambda expressions, it would be appreciated.

EDIT: Ok, the answers posted are great, it appears that the example does not need a Lambda to satisfy the solution. I will take a look at the reference links though.

Answer (score 7):

You don't really need lambdas to do that all you would need to do is

```
var ObjectProperty = Combo.EditValue.Property;
```

I'm not sure a lambda is going to make that any more readable for you.

Here are some books you might want to take a look at to learn Lambdas in more detail, and also why you'd use them:

[More Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321485890)

[C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/)

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing and trying to see if there was any nuance I was missing in the question. Looks reasonable though :)

Comment: I was about to post the same thing.

Comment: Yeah I'm still looking for a good lambda reference for the guy, though

Comment: Manning publications has a book on Lambda in Depth, I believe that should be good, as I have been impressed with the other books I have gotten from them.

Answer (score 0):

Combining those into one line, you run the risk of a NullReferenceException, by checking the Property property on EditValue. :)  But, [here is a really great tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/FP-Tutorial.aspx) on C# 3.0 and functional programming.

Comment: There's a risk of a NullReferenceException when the code is on two lines as well, unless you add in some extra code to check first ...

Comment: He ran the risk anyway, he wasn't checking the first place =P  He would need to check either way he went.

Comment: It's true, I just didn't like the way Combo.EditValue.Property looked on the page, so I skipped it. :)

Answer (score 0):

this does not appear to need a lambda.
Can't you just use

```
var ObjectProperty = Combo.EditValue.Property
```

As far as lambda references try [101 LINQ Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) for starters.